# Keras - adding an attention layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am building an encoder-decoder architecture to do text summarization on restaurant reviews. I have been following this [guide](https://blog.paperspace.com/implement-seq2seq-for-text-summarization-keras/). My model has 3 LSTM layers for the the encoder and one LSTM layer for decoding. This is what it looks like right now:

```
latent_dim = 300

embedding_dim = 200

encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(max_review_len, ))

enc_emb = Embedding(x_voc, embedding_dim,
                    trainable=True)(encoder_inputs)

encoder_lstm1 = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True,
                     return_state=True, dropout=0.4,
                     recurrent_dropout=0.4)

encoder_lstm2 = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True,
                     return_state=True, dropout=0.4,
                     recurrent_dropout=0.4)
(encoder_output2, state_h2, state_c2) = encoder_lstm2(encoder_output1)

encoder_lstm3 = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True,
                     return_sequences=True, dropout=0.4,
                     recurrent_dropout=0.4)
(encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c) = encoder_lstm3(encoder_output2)

decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, ))

dec_emb_layer = Embedding(y_voc, embedding_dim, trainable=True)
dec_emb = dec_emb_layer(decoder_inputs)

decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True,
                    return_state=True, dropout=0.4,
                    recurrent_dropout=0.2)
(decoder_outputs, decoder_fwd_state, decoder_back_state) = \
    decoder_lstm(dec_emb, initial_state=[state_h, state_c])

decoder_concat_input = Concatenate(axis=-1, name='concat_layer')([decoder_outputs, attn_out])

decoder_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(y_voc, activation='softmax'))
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)

model.summary()
```

In order to improve the summarization results I would like to add an **attention layer**, ideally like this (as suggested by this [guide](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/06/comprehensive-guide-text-summarization-using-deep-learning-python/)):

```
Attention layer attn_layer = AttentionLayer(name='attention_layer') 
attn_out, attn_states = attn_layer([encoder_outputs, decoder_outputs]) 

decoder_concat_input = Concatenate(axis=-1, name='concat_layer')([decoder_outputs, attn_out])
```

The guide suggests doing the following import:

```
from attention import Attention
```

However this leads to an invalid syntax error on the declaration of the `attn_layer`variable. Even resolving the error leads to an `ÀttentionLayer not defined` error.

I've turned to the [attention_keras](https://github.com/thushv89/attention_keras) module which seems to be just what I need but `pip install attention_keras` is unsuccesful:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement attention_keras (from versions: none)
```

Comment: Keras has attention layers: https://keras.io/api/layers/attention_layers/attention/ You are following outdated websites, the keras website even has examples.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I'm not sure I understand how I can implement this in my architecture. In order for it to work I would need it to return ```attn_out```. However it is not quite clear to me how to obtain it

Comment: The Keras documentation literally has an example in the link I provided, I already suggested to stop using outdated websites and follow proper documentation, here is an example to build a full transformer too: https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy The guide you linked is outdated as it includes the ```tensorflow-text```which seems to be obsolete. I'm trying to build an encoder-decoder architecture, not a transformer. I solved the problem and will now post the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using this import:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Attention
```

The attention layer now takes the encoder and decoder outputs in order to create the desired attention distribution:

```
attention = Attention()
attention_outputs = attention([decoder_outputs, encoder_outputs])

concatenate = Concatenate(axis=-1)
decoder_concat_input = concatenate([decoder_outputs, attention_outputs])

# Dense layer
decoder_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(y_voc, activation='softmax'))
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_concat_input)
```

I followed this [guide](https://saturncloud.io/blog/concatenating-attention-layer-with-decoder-input-in-seq2seq-model-on-keras/)